# Fibered category: The object is not in the pullback, what is it mapped to?

Tags: category-theory

Given two objects and their intersection which is the pullback, what is the pullback of any sub-object that is not in the intersection?

For instance given the category:

$
\begin{matrix}
    4 & \xrightarrow{p_{2}} & \{4,5,6,7 \}
    \\
     p_{1} \; \downarrow && \beta \downarrow
    \\
     \{1,2,3,4\} & \xrightarrow{\alpha} & c =\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} 
\end{matrix}
$

Comment: What does “the pullback of $5$” mean?

Comment: I was thinking the pullback of $5$ by $c$ should be $\{\emptyset \}$.

Comment: It's just because its so abstract for me even as an intermediate level student, @qiaochu, is there is a composition $\{ \emptyset\} \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow c$?

Comment: What do you mean by "the pullback of $5$ by $c$"? You haven't defined $c$ here but I assume it's some kind of set containing $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 \}$. What two morphisms do you want to take the pullback of?

Comment: That would be $\alpha$ and $p_{1}$..

Comment: As written, $p_1$ is a map $\{ 4 \} \to \{ 4 \}$ and $\alpha$ is a map $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \} \to c$, so they don't have the same codomain. And neither of these maps involves $5$ so I don't see how this is the same as the question you're trying to ask about $5$. Again, what two morphisms are you trying to take the pullback of?

Comment: Well I pick the maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then.

Comment: As you've already computed, their pullback is their intersection which is $\{ 4 \}$. What is this for? Is this part of an exercise or what?

Comment: Oh well I was just looking to find this isomorphism between the pullback of an object like $5$ here and the pullback of another object like $4$ or even $3$ in the context of stacks.  If there's no pullback then I take it there isn't any such "descent data"-type object $x_{i}$ that is over $5$ which is isomorphic to an object $x_{j}$ over $3$ or $4$.

Comment: Its for stacks and their descent datum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The concept you need to consider is "diagram commutes". The pullback diagram creates a subset of $\alpha \times \beta$ which contains only the elements of $(a,b)$ which makes the diagram commute.

Comment: So in the category which I added, there is no pullback of the element which I'm representing by $5$ by the map $\alpha$ in the descent data?